# Upload video from meteor and cordova

Tags: javascript, android, file, cordova, meteor

I have a problem for uploading video from Cordova application with meteor.
Capturing video is ok but when I do readData as DataURL, the result is empty like "content:video/mp4;base64, "
nothing after base64, someone know what happens?

Edit 1: I think the probleme come from permission, is it possible?

```
navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(function (mediaFiles) {
  var i, path, len;
  for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {
    path = mediaFiles[i].fullPath;
    var file = mediaFiles;

    var FR = new FileReader();

    FR.onerror = function (err) {
      console.log("ERROR");
    }

    FR.onloadend = function (encodedFile) {

      var src = encodedFile.target.result; 
      src = src.split("base64,");

      var contentAsBase64EncodedString = src[1] //EMPTY;
      var url = Session.get("lat") + "_" + new Date().toJSON() + ".mp4";
      console.log("on upload");
      Meteor.call('uploadVideo', contentAsBase64EncodedString , url);
    }
    FR.readAsDataURL( mediaFiles[i]);

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, follow this:

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(imageUri, function(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.file(function(file) {
        file.name = filename;
        template.cordovaFile = file;
    });
});

var file = template.cordovaFile;
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onloadend = function(e) {
    var fileBlob = internals.dataURItoBlob(e.target.result);
    if (fileBlob) {

     uploader.send(fileBlob, function (error, downloadUrl) {
                if (error) {
                    return cb(error);
                }

                return cb(null);
            });

    }
}
reader.readAsDataURL(file);



/**
 * Converts a data uri into Blob object
 * @param dataURI
 * @returns {Blob}
 */
internals.dataURItoBlob = function(dataURI) {
    var byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
    var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
    var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
    for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
        ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return new Blob([ab], { type: 'image/jpeg' });
};
```